# How to constraint a function parameter pointer to a given (RAM) section?

Tags: c

Let's say, I have a function foo that take a pointer to a buffer as argument. The function does a time-critical operation.

```
void foo(uint8_t *buffer_p)
{
  // time-critical operation on *buffer_p
}
```

I work on an embedded system that has different RAM section:

- one cache-like fast memory, called "fast"
- one big DDR without cache, called "slow"

The problem I have, is that I don't know from where `foo` will be called, and if the buffer lies in the "slow" section, the time-critical operation in `foo` will be too slow!

```
__attribute__((section("fast"))) uint8_t fast_buffer[100];
foo(fast_buffer); // everything OK

__attribute__((section("slow"))) uint8_t slow_buffer[100];
foo(slow_buffer); // operation fails with not deterministic results
```

Question:

- best case: how to constrain the parameter buffer_p, so that the compiler gives me an error
- or: is the best I can get, an `assert` inside `foo()` to check the address of `buffer_p`?
  `assert((buffer_p >= SECTION_FAST_START) && (buffer_p < SECTION_FAST_END))`, with symbols appropriatly defined in linker-script.

Comment: Not sure of your technology but do you have a "ramfuncs" option in your environment to place the function into RAM so it runs from there rather than Flash?  We do this for time critical functions.

Comment: The function is already in RAM, so the code runs fast. The problem is really just the access to buffer_p, which may be too slow.

Comment: do you want to add gcc tag?

Comment: Ahhh...  I see.  I'd probably do the assert option, but this is a good question which I'm interested to follow!

Comment: I do not think this is possible because object addresses are evaluated at link time. In other words,  `__builtin_constant_p(fast_buffer)` is false.

Comment: Usually on embedded system the given constraint on memory can also be applied to pointers, so declaring void `foo(__attribute__((section("fast"))) uint8_t *buffer_p)` may only accept pointers labeled with the same manner.

Comment: @dalfaB Unfortunately, the compilers does not accept section attributes on function parameters.